# Activity - Service Inconsistent data with Realm

Tags: android, android-service, realm

I have problems with data stored in a Realm Database. If I change a value on the MainActivity, when I try to read it from a NotificationListenerService, the data is incorrect.

This is my model:

```
public class Model extends RealmObject {

    String name;
    boolean checked;


    public Model() {}

    public Model(String name, boolean checked) {
        this.name = name;
        this.checked = checked;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean isChecked() {
        return checked;
    }

    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        this.checked = checked;
    }

}
```

I populate the database from the Application class:

```
public class ExampleApplication extends Application{

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext()).deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded().build();
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration);
        Realm.getDefaultInstance().beginTransaction();
        Realm.getDefaultInstance().copyToRealm(new Model("Test1", true));
        Realm.getDefaultInstance().copyToRealm(new Model("Test2", true));
        Realm.getDefaultInstance().commitTransaction();
    }
}
```

I have an activity with:

- a button with a link to Notification Listener services on device settings
- a textview that shows the state of the model (checked or not)
- a button to change the checked value of the model

This is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnEnableService;
    Button btnChangeValue;
    TextView tvStatus;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnEnableService = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_enable_service);
        btnChangeValue = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_change_value);
        tvStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_status);

        btnEnableService.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS));
                }catch(ActivityNotFoundException anfe){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Your device not supports Notification Listener Service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        btnChangeValue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                boolean status = Realm.getDefaultInstance().where(Model.class).equalTo("name", "Test1").findFirst().isChecked();
                Realm.getDefaultInstance().beginTransaction();
                Realm.getDefaultInstance().where(Model.class).equalTo("name", "Test1").findFirst().setChecked(!status);
                Realm.getDefaultInstance().commitTransaction();
                updateView();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        updateView();
    }

    private void updateView(){
        boolean status = Realm.getDefaultInstance().where(Model.class).equalTo("name", "Test1").findFirst().isChecked();
        tvStatus.setText("Status: " + status);
    }
}
```

When I click on the btnChangeValue button, I change the value on Realm and the textview is updated with the new value. All OK for now.

On the other hand, I have a service to listen the device notifications. It's very simple and only shows the status value of the model on LogCat:

```
public class CustomNotificationListenerService extends NotificationListenerService{

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        super.onNotificationPosted(sbn);
        boolean status = Realm.getDefaultInstance().where(Model.class).equalTo("name", "Test1").findFirst().isChecked();
        Log.i("XXX", "Status: " + status);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        super.onNotificationRemoved(sbn);
    }
}
```

My problem is that the checked value of the model is inconsistent, I get different values from the MainActivity and the NotificationListenerService.

What do I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing for hours, I solved my problem **closing the Realm instance after every operation**.

So, data is consistent and I can query from NotificationListenerService and MainActivity.

**ExampleApplication**

```
public class ExampleApplication extends Application{

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext()).deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded().build();
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration);
        Realm mRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        mRealm.beginTransaction();
        mRealm.copyToRealm(new Model("Test1", true));
        mRealm.copyToRealm(new Model("Test2", true));
        mRealm.commitTransaction();
        mRealm.close();
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
...
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    btnChangeValue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Realm mRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
            boolean status = mRealm.where(Model.class).equalTo("name", "Test1").findFirst().isChecked();
            mRealm.beginTransaction();
            mRealm.where(Model.class).equalTo("name", "Test1").findFirst().setChecked(!status);
            mRealm.commitTransaction();
            mRealm.close();
            updateView();
        }
    });
}
...
```

**CustomNotificationListenerService**

```
...
@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    super.onNotificationPosted(sbn);
    Realm mRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    boolean status = mRealm.where(Model.class).equalTo("name", "Test1").findFirst().isChecked();
    mRealm.close();
    Log.i("XXX", "Status: " + status);
}
...
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: This has a huge memory leak, you're not supposed to cal getInstance for every method you want to call, call it once, assign it to a variable, and use that

Comment: Every call to getInstance() must have a matching close()

Comment: Yes, my code represents a very simple case and I tried to post it as clear as possible. 
The best practice is, as you said, get the instance, save it on a variable, use it, and **close** it.
I had to set the default config again on each call, before get the instance, because if not, the data were inconsistent too.
I will edit the post.

Comment: Setting a default should only have to be done once. If its not working, something else is wrong

Comment: I know, but here is all the code, and if I don't do this workaround, data is inconsistent... :(

Comment: @TimCastelijns. I was wrong. I had created the two items (Test1 and Test2) on every execution, so database had many objects. I solved my problem deleting the existing objects before add them, and of course, closing the realm instance after each use it.